# Appending to an array via overloading the operator[]

Tags: c++

I'd like to define a construct `a[] = 1` in C++  that lets me append to an custom array object  instead of using something like `push_back()`.

Is it possible to achieve this via some operator overload in c++?

I'm thinking of `[]` returning a reference that overloads `=`. However `operator [](void)` is invalid, but maybe there is some trick?

Comment: You can't append to arrys in C++.

Comment: Why aren't you using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or one of the other available containers?

Comment: after rethink I don't think it's a duplicate. Nevertheless are you aware of the syntax you'd like to use will require additional class and the need of passing some dummy parameter to your `operator[]` as there is no way to change the number of parameters in `operator[]` overload (you can't even change the number to be greater than 1!)?

Comment: What is wring with `push_back()`?

Comment: Arrays have no push_back function.

Comment: @Galik: I use `a[x]=1;` and `b=a[x]` instead of `a.set(x,1)` and `b=a.get(x)`. So having the same style for append seems natural. I guess there is no trick.

Comment: They do different things. `a[x] = 1` works fine using `std::vector` as long as you made it at least big enough for `x` items. `push_back()` is when you wish to add a new item to the end increasing its size.

Comment: @Galik: I know that.  Object "a" is my own class . I call it array, I should have called it custom array object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My strong advice is to just create a `push_back` method. It's idiomatic and people now what it does. Any other trick would be surprising for the users.

However if you insist here are some tricks you can do:

```
struct To_back {};
constexpr To_back to_back;

struct X
{
    auto operator[](To_back) -> Back_inserter_proxy
    {
        return Back_inserter_proxy{*this};
    }
};
```

```
X x;

x[to_back] = 24;
```

or:

```
struct X
{
    auto operator%=(int elem)
    {
        // push back here
    }
    // or
    auto operator<<(int elem)
    {
        // push back here
    }
};
```

```
X x
x %= 24;
// or
x << 24;
```

However I reiterate: I strongly recommend against these *tricks* especially since there is a simple idiomatic way of doing it: `push_back`.

Comment: @bolov: I guess I skip the `a[]=` idea.

Comment: @KonradEisele that's not possible with the current C++ syntax.

Comment: @bolov:  I wonder weather this will appear in some future c++ standard... Somethink like: `operator[](int x, int y)` to overload a[1,2]... Thanks, Question is solved.

Comment: @Konrad - It has been considered, but `a[1,2]` already is a correct (but rather useless) syntax using the dreaded comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

> However `operator [](void)` is invalid, but maybe there is some trick?

No there's no point or trick to get around that.

> Is it possible to achieve this via some operator overload in c++?

The closest you can get is an indexing operator overload that would automatically resize an interned `std::vector` in case the index is currently out of bounds:

```
template<typename T>
class AutoArray {
    std::vector<T> v;
public:
    T& operator[](size_t index) {
        if(index >= v.size()) {
            v.resize(index + 1);
        }
        return v[index];
    }
};
```

That won't be very efficient when e.g. used in an arbitrary indexing loop though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun. Theoretically you could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class U>
struct Arr {
    template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    U &operator[](T i) { return v[i]; }
    U &operator[](decltype(nullptr)){
        v.push_back({});
        return v[v.size() - 1];
    }
private:
std::vector<U> v;
};

int main() {
    Arr<int> a;
    a[{}] = 100;
    a[{}] = 2;
    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
100
2
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UUUdS7BPHd9DTOCt)

But don't do it... Still think `push_back` is just simpler.